# Django/Celery 4.3 - jobs seem to fail randomly

Tags: django, celery

These are the tasks in `tasks.py`:

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def verify_external_video(video_id, media_id, video_type):
    return True
```

I am calling verify_external_video 1000+ times from a custom Django command I run from CLI

```
verify_external_video.delay("1", "2", "3")
```

In Flower, I am then monitoring the success or failure of the jobs. A random number of jobs fail, others succeed...

[image]

Those that fail, do so because of two reasons that I just cannot understand:

```
NotRegistered('lstv_api_v1.tasks.verify_external_video')
```

if it's not registered, why are 371 succeedings?

and...

```
TypeError: verify_external_video() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Again, a mystery, as I quit `Celery` and `Flower`, and run them AGAIN from scratch before running my CLI Django command. There is no code living anywhere where `verify_external_video()` takes 1 parameter. And if this is the case... why are SOME of the calls successful?

This type of failure isn't sequential. I can have 3 successful jobs, followed by one that does not succeed, followed by success again, so it's not a *timing* issue.

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Are you sure you are aware of all celery workers that are connected to your broker?  The most likely scenario is that there are stray workers out there that are connecting to the broker and trying to consume tasks.  If on local, it may be celery running from other projects connecting to the same celery broker.  If you are using redis, you may want to try putting celery on a different database to verify,

Comment: It's possible. One of the other effects I'm getting is "stale" signatures complaints where Celery complains about trying to call a function with the wrong number of parameters, although it was started from scratch with both the TASK and the ttask caller supporting the signature in the code at that time. It's like a stale call that comes out of persistence somehow.

Comment: @2ps you were right. I had a number of rogue celery processes running around from previous "violent" CTRL-C's which prevented graceful termination of what was running. If you respond with an answer, I can credit you for it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Short: I had a number of rogue celery processes running around from previous "violent" CTRL-C's which prevented graceful termination of what was running.

Comment: How did you find those processes and how did you kill them?